# Problema ao registrar uma diretiva no Tomcat usando o Eclipse no Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, linux, ubuntu, tomcat

Bom dia

Estou com problema ao colocar essa diretiva `-Dorg.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO=false` nos argumentos de VM do `Tomcat 7`, o mesmo não salva as configuração.

Ja dei permissão na pasta mas mesmo assim o problema continua.

Salvei o `Eclipse` e `Tomcat` na pasta `opt`.

Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicione essa diretiva na variável `JAVA_OPTS`, abra um terminal e digite:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="- Dorg.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO=false"
```

Comment: Cara, não encontrei dentro da pasta `bin` esse arquivo.

Comment: Uma dúvida iniciante, eu coloco no final do arquivo?

Comment: Quando vc fala acima o arquivo seria o `catalina.sh`?

Comment: @Macario1983 Não o arquivo `/etc/default/tomcat7`.

Comment: Cara eu não instalei o `tomcat 7` via `terminal`, eu até instalei mas não consegui direcionar via `Eclipse` qual a pasta onde fica alocado o servidor

Comment: Tente então através do *export*. Digite no terminal:`export JAVA_OPTS="- Dorg.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO=false"`

Comment: Fiz isso e deu cara, só acho estranho porque não consigo gravar via `Eclipse`